# Django signup/login not directing users to ?next=/my/url

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

## Setup

I use `[django-allauth][1]` for user accounts.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^login$', allauth.account.views.login, name="account_login"),
url(r'^join$', allauth.account.views.signup, name="account_signup"),
```

.

```
# settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/me' 
LOGIN_URL = '/join'  # users sent here if they run into @login_required decorator
# To collect additional info if user signs up by email:
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'allauth.account.forms.WinnerSignupForm'
```

.

That custom signup form:

```
# account/forms.py
from .models import Winner, FriendCode
class WinnerSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
        This is the additional custom form to accompany the default fields email/password (and maybe username)
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Winner
        fields = ('author_display_name','signupcode',)
        widgets = {'author_display_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                            'placeholder': _('Display Name'), # 'Display Name',
                                            'autofocus': 'autofocus',
                                            })
                  ,
                  'signupcode': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                            'placeholder': _('Invite code (optional)'), 
                                            'autofocus': 'autofocus'
                                            })
                  }


    def signup(self, request, user):
        # custom code that performs some account setup for the user
        # just runs a procedure; there's no "return" at end of this block
```

I don't think my custom `WinnerSignupForm` is causing the issue, because the problem persists even if I disable it (i.e., I comment out this line from `settings.py`: `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'allauth.account.forms.WinnerSignupForm'`)

---

## Behaviour

### 0. Without `?next=/some/url` parameter:

Thanks to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`, if I visit `example.com/join` or `example.com/login`, I'll wind up on `example.com/me`

That is fine.

### 1. If I am already logged in, everything works as expected:

A) If I visit `https://example.com/login?next=/some/url`, 
I'm immediately forwarded to `https://example.com/some/url` (without being asked to log in, since I am already logged in).
I conclude the /login view is correctly reading the `next=/some/url` argument.

B) Similarly, if I visit `https://example.com/join?next=/some/url`, I'm immediately forwarded to `https://example.com/some/url`.
I conclude the /join view is also correctly reading the `next=/some/url` argument.

### 2. If I log in or sign up by social account, everything works as expected

This uses `allauth/socialaccount`

After I sign up or log in, I'm forwarded to `https://example.com/some/url`

#### ***However, here's the problem:***

### 3. But! If I log in by email, ?next=/some/url is being ignored:

A) If I visit `https://example.com/login?next=/some/url`, I'm brought first to the /login page.
**If I log in by email**, I'm then forwarded to `https://example.com/me`
For some reason now, the `?next=` is not over-riding the default `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings. 
(**If I log in via Twitter**, the `?next=` paramter is correctly read, and I'm brought to `https://example.com/some/url`.)

B) Similarly, if I visit `https://example.com/join?next=/some/url`, I'm brought first to the /join (signup) page, and after successful login by email, I'm brought to `/me`, i.e., the fallback `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` defined in `settings.py`.

Inspecting the POST data in the signup/login form, the "next" parameter is there alright: `{"next": "/some/url", "username": "myusername", "password": "..."}`

---

## More context

Extracts from `django-allauth`:

```
# allauth/account/views.py
from .utils import (get_next_redirect_url, complete_signup,
                    get_login_redirect_url, perform_login,
                    passthrough_next_redirect_url)
...
class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
                 AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "account/signup.html"
    form_class = SignupForm
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    success_url = None

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup', self.form_class)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (get_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                     self.redirect_field_name)
               or self.success_url)
        return ret
    ...
```

.

```
# allauth/account/utils.py
def get_next_redirect_url(request, redirect_field_name="next"):
    """
    Returns the next URL to redirect to, if it was explicitly passed
    via the request.
    """
    redirect_to = request.GET.get(redirect_field_name)
    if not is_safe_url(redirect_to):
        redirect_to = None
    return redirect_to

def get_login_redirect_url(request, url=None, redirect_field_name="next"):
    redirect_url \
        = (url
           or get_next_redirect_url(request,
                                    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name)
           or get_adapter().get_login_redirect_url(request))
    return redirect_url

_user_display_callable = None

...
```

I'm pretty sure it was originally working when I installed `[django-allauth][1]` out of the box. I must have somehow interfered to break this `?next=/some/url` functionality, though I can't remember the last time it was working or find out what I've done to mess things up.

Any tips on troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

(In case relevant -- perhaps settings are not being read correctly; 
`ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_PASSWORD_RESET = True` in `settings.py` seems to be ignored, users have to log in after resetting their password.)

Comment: @Akshay I added an extra check for `request.POST.get('next', '')` within `get_login_redirect_url` in `account/adapter.py` -- see answer below. It's not a completely satisfactory answer, since it doesn't explain how I got to the position of needing this amendment in the first place, but it effectively does solve my problem, hope it does for you too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

@Akshay, the following work-around worked for me.

I added the following lines to `allauth/account/adapter.py`, within the `get_login_redirect_url` sub-function.

```
goto = request.POST.get('next', '')
if goto:
    return goto
```

To clarify, the result looks like this:

```
class DefaultAccountAdapter(object):
    # no change to stash_verified_email, unstash_verified_email, etc.

    # edit only get_login_redirect_url as follows
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        """
        Returns the default URL to redirect to after logging in.  Note
        that URLs passed explicitly (e.g. by passing along a `next`
        GET parameter) take precedence over the value returned here.
        """
        assert request.user.is_authenticated()
        url = getattr(settings, "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME", None)
        if url:
            warnings.warn("LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME is deprecated, simply"
                      " use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL with a URL name",
                      DeprecationWarning)
        else:
            url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        # Added 20170301 - look again for ?next parameter, as work-around fallback
        goto = request.POST.get('next', '')
        if goto:
            return goto
            print "found next url in adapter.py"
        else:
            print "no sign of next in adapter.py"
        # end of work-around manually added bit
        return resolve_url(url)

        # leave remainder of fn untouched 
        # get_logout_redirect_url, get_email_confirmation_redirect_url, etc.
```

I still don't know how I broke this functionality in the first place, so I won't mark my answer as accepted/best answer. It does, however, [resolve](http://starecat.com/content/wp-content/uploads/dolores-restaurant-when-your-code-is-a-mess-but-everything-works-out-in-the-end.jpg) the issue I had, so I am happy. Hope this is useful to others.